# how to spawn multiple ssh requests in a twisted server?

Tags: ssh, twisted

from twisted ssh example docs: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/conch/examples/sshsimpleclient.py,

we learn that twisted need a reactor to spawn a ssh request:

```
protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, SimpleTransport).connectTCP(HOST, 22)
reactor.run()
```

and i want to know how can we spawn ssh request in a  twisted server ?  there is already a reactor in a twisted server.

Comment: The example seems to show you what you need to do.  I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

you may review examples how to use it
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/conch/examples/

Reactor is already embedded into twisted and you called it with reactor.run()
You need to write callbacks for handling connection results.